# Task keeps looping when it should be finished

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, task

I'm trying to let  my accounts do multiple logins with tasks. I am by no means an expert, I've only just started, but I'm stuck with the following problem I have.

For some reason the tasks keep looping, but they should not. I can't really figure out what the problem is, so I figured that someone on here might know the solution.

```
public async void Login()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                MyEmail = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
                MyPassword = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
                MySecurity = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
            });
            var loginDetails = new LoginDetails(MyEmail, MyPassword, MySecurity, Platform.Ps3);
            client[i] = new FutClient();
            var loginResponse = await client[i].LoginAsync(loginDetails);
            MessageBox.Show("Succesful login");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string foutMelding = ex.InnerException.ToString();
            ListViewItem exception = new ListViewItem(time);
            exception.SubItems.Add(foutMelding);
            listView2.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => listView2.Items.Add(exception)));
        }
    }
}
public void StartLogin()
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[objectsToCreate];
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = new Task(() => Login());
    }
    foreach (Task task in tasks)
    {
        task.Start();
    }
}
```

I call the StartLogin method with a button in my form. It then proceeds to login the accounts, but for some reason the tasks keep looping and I really can't figure out the reason, since I only just started with using Tasks. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: what is `objectsToCreate`'s value? have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Its value is 4. Yes, I have tried, but I'm really at a loss, can't figure it out.

Comment: Please see the code example I added to my answer. It should fix the issue you're seeing as well as clean up the code somewhat, making it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, I would expect the logic in the loop inside the `Login()` method to execute 16 times: 4 times for each time the `Login()` method itself is called, due to the `for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)` statement at the beginning of that method; and that, 4 times because you are creating 4 tasks to call the method.

It's hard to know what you meant to write, but I'm guessing you want to remove the loop from the `Login()` method itself. It looks like an artifact left over from a previous implementation attempt.

As an aside: it is a little odd to be mixing invocation of an `async` method with an explicit `Task` invocation of that method. It seems to me you could accomplish much the same result by simply calling the `Login()` method four times (minus the loop in the `Login()` method, of course).

Here's how I'd write the code:

```
public async void Login()
{
    try
    {
        MyEmail = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text;
        MyPassword = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text;
        MySecurity = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
        var loginDetails = new LoginDetails(MyEmail, MyPassword, MySecurity, Platform.Ps3);
        client[i] = new FutClient();
        var loginResponse = await client[i].LoginAsync(loginDetails);
        MessageBox.Show("Succesful login");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string foutMelding = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        ListViewItem exception = new ListViewItem(time);
        exception.SubItems.Add(foutMelding);
        listView2.Items.Add(exception);
    }
}
public void StartLogin()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToCreate; i++)
    {
        var _ = Login();
    }
}
```

Note that, in this approach, since the `Login()` method is initially called from the UI thread (I presume...you didn't show the actual caller of the `StartLogin()` method, you don't need to use `Invoke()` or `BeginInvoke()` when accessing UI elements in that method.

(The `var _ =` is just to keep the compiler from complaining that I didn't `await` the `async` method. Here, that's on purpose :) ).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't loop indefinitely - it executes exactly 16 times. This is because you essentially have a doubly nested for loop - one in your StartLogin method, and one in your Login method. Perhaps you aren't expecting the contents of your Login method to execute 4 times each time your Login method is called?